# Creating file in HDFS but not appending any content

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, flume, hortonworks-data-platform, flume-ng

I am using a HTTP-Source to put JSON files into HDFS (Single node SANDBOX).

The file is created in the correct directory however nothing is appended to the file. Could you verify my flume.conf before I start debugging the HTTP-Source?

```
#################################################################
# Name the components on this agent
#################################################################

hdfs-agent.sources = httpsource
hdfs-agent.sinks = hdfssink
hdfs-agent.channels = channel1

#################################################################
# Describe source
#################################################################

# Source node
hdfs-agent.sources.httpsource.type = http 
hdfs-agent.sources.httpsource.port = 5140
hdfs-agent.sources.httpsource.handler = org.apache.flume.source.http.JSONHandler

#################################################################
# Describe Sink
#################################################################

# Sink hdfs
hdfs-agent.sinks.hdfssink.type = hdfs
hdfs-agent.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.path = hdfs://sandbox:8020/user/flume/node
hdfs-agent.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
hdfs-agent.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.batchSize = 1
hdfs-agent.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.rollSize = 0
hdfs-agent.sinks.hdfssink.hdfs.rollCount = 0

#################################################################
# Describe channel
#################################################################

# Channel memory
hdfs-agent.channels.channel1.type = memory
hdfs-agent.channels.channel1.capacity = 1000
hdfs-agent.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 100


#################################################################
# Bind the source and sink to the channel
#################################################################

hdfs-agent.sources.httpsource.channels = channel1
hdfs-agent.sinks.hdfssink.channel = channel1
```

I am currently just trying to test it by starting small:

```
[{"text": "Hi Flume this Node"}]
```

So I am thinking my batchSize/rollSize/rollCount could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

batchSize,rollSize, rollCount values are fine.
Setting rollSize and rollCount to 0 will disable the file rolling feature.

hdfs-agent.sources.httpsource.type should be set to `org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource`

The format of data sent to http source should be

`[{"headers" : {"a":"b", "c":"d"},"body": "random_body"}, {"headers" : {"e": "f"},"body": "random_body2"}].`

I tested sending using the data you used ([{"text": "Hi Flume this Node"}]). Nothing was getting appended to my file as there is not "body" attribute. But when I posted the following, data got appended to my file.

```
 curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -d '[{  "headers" : {           "timestamp" : "434324343", "host" :"random_host.example.com", "field1" : "val1"            },  "body" : "random_body"  }]' http://localhost:5140.
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Like arathim pointed out org.apache.flume.source.http.JSONHandler expects the Flume Event Format. If you want to spool your own JSON, you'll need to create your own Handler. This is an example of a Handler that takes any JSON:

```
public class GenericJSONInputHandler implements HTTPSourceHandler {

    protected static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GenericJSONInputHandler.class);
    protected static final String TYPE = "type";


    public GenericJSONInputHandler() {
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public List<Event> getEvents(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        String charset = request.getCharacterEncoding();
        // UTF-8 is default for JSON. If no charset is specified, UTF-8 is to
        // be assumed.
        if (charset == null) {
            LOG.debug("Charset is null, default charset of UTF-8 should be used.");
        }

        List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>(0);
        try {
            String json = reader.readLine();
            LOG.debug("Received line with size " + json.length());
            while (json != null) {
                List<Event> e = createEvents(json);
                if (e !=null) {
                    eventList.addAll(e);
                }
                json = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new HTTPBadRequestException("Request has invalid JSON Syntax.", ex);
        }

        return eventList;
    }

    protected List<Event> createEvents(String json) {
        try {
            if (isValidJSON(json)) {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                headers.put(TIMESTAMP, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                headers.put(TYPE, "default");
                return Arrays.asList(EventBuilder.withBody(json.getBytes(), headers));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isValidJSON(final String json) {
        boolean valid = false;
        try {
            final JsonParser parser = new ObjectMapper().getFactory()
                .createParser(json);
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            }
            valid = true;
        }
        catch (JsonParseException jpe) {
            jpe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return valid;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Context context) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this custom handler then just placed in the flume directory? How does it get picked up?

Comment: Compile it and place it into a jar, that jar has to be placed in your FLUME_HOME/lib directory. The change hdfs-agent.sources.httpsource.handler to point to your own implementation.